# How to Stripe Subscription Array value

Tags: arrays, stripe-payments

How to get `Current_Period_end` value, plan Array id in below array code?

```
Stripe_List Object(
[_apiKey:protected] => sk_test_JankU8huwVhFYlfK7hLp4SPs
[_values:protected] => Array
    (
        [object] => list
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Stripe_Subscription Object
                    (
                        [_apiKey:protected] => sk_test_JankU8huwVhFYlfK7hLp4SPs
                        [_values:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => sub_6u1oFCUsWyRKKp
                                [object] => subscription
                                [application_fee_percent] => 
                                [cancel_at_period_end] => 
                                [canceled_at] => 
                                [current_period_end] => 1450268469
                                [current_period_start] => 1447676469
                                [customer] => cus_6u1oHUF0VRkpU3
                                [discount] => 
                                [ended_at] => 
                                [metadata] => Stripe_AttachedObject Object
                                    (
                                        [_apiKey:protected] => sk_test_JankU8huwVhFYlfK7hLp4SPs
                                        [_values:protected] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                        [_unsavedValues:protected] => Stripe_Util_Set Object
                                            (
                                                [_elts:Stripe_Util_Set:private] => Array
                                                    (
                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [_transientValues:protected] => Stripe_Util_Set Object
                                            (
                                                [_elts:Stripe_Util_Set:private] => Array
                                                    (
                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [plan] => Stripe_Plan Object
                                    (
                                        [_apiKey:protected] => sk_test_JankU8huwVhFYlfK7hLp4SPs
                                        [_values:protected] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 2
                                                [object] => plan
                                                [amount] => 699
                                                [created] => 1441108548
                                                [currency] => gbp
                                                [interval] => month
                                                [interval_count] => 1
                                                [livemode] => 
                                                [metadata] => Stripe_AttachedObject Object
                                                    (
                                                        [_apiKey:protected] => sk_test_JankU8huwVhFYlfK7hLp4SPs
                                                        [_values:protected] => Array
                                                            (
                                                            )

                                                        [_unsavedValues:protected] => Stripe_Util_Set Object
                                                            (
                                                                [_elts:Stripe_Util_Set:private] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [_transientValues:protected] => Stripe_Util_Set Object
                                                            (
                                                                [_elts:Stripe_Util_Set:private] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array
                                                            (
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [name] => Basic
                                                [statement_descriptor] => 
                                                [trial_period_days] => 15
                                                [statement_description] => 
                                            )
```

How to take that `Period_end` value in given array? I don't know how to get inside array details inside that object array in my previous stripe account

I am retrieving the subscription value to customer using `$customer->subscription` but now retrieving subscription using `$customer->subscriptions` in that subscrition object getting my subscription array is correct or not?